# Do I have to fork a server program as an "C" child process in order for correct interprocess communication to take place?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, linux, pointers

I would like to implement interprocess communication between an Ubuntu Linux 15.10 mono 4.1.2 C# recorder client and Ubuntu Linux 15.10 mono 4.1.2 C# video server using a C++ mutex  class and C++ event class  which harnesses pthreads, shm_open and mmap.

The recorder client and video server reside on the same Ubuntu Linux machine. In addition, a Windows 7 C# client running on a separate machine communicates with an Ubuntu Linux 15.10 C# client-server program using TCP/IP sockets.

In *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment Second Edition* by W. Richard Stevens and Stephen A. Rago, I read page  489 which states

> A memory-mapped region is inherited by a child across a fork (since it's part of the parent's address space) , but for the same reason, is not inherited by the new program across  an  exec

I need to know if I have to fork the video server program as an "C" child process in order for interprocess communication to take place by casting the mmap return value to a pthread_mutex_t pointer . I want to share pthread mutex and pthread condition variable between the video server process and recorder client process.

Have I confused threads with processes?

Boost wrote an interesting article about this topic which  I have extracted an excerpt from shown below,

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_region_object_limitations

Limitations When Constructing Objects In Mapped Regions 
Offset pointers instead of raw pointers

When two processes create a mapped region of the same mappable object, two processes can communicate writing and reading that memory. A process could construct a C++ object in that memory so that the second process can use it. However, a mapped region shared by multiple processes, can't hold any C++ object, because not every class is ready to be a process-shared object, specially, if the mapped region is mapped in different address in each process.

When placing objects in a mapped region and mapping that region in different address in every process, raw pointers are a problem since they are only valid for the process that placed them there. To solve this, Boost.Interprocess offers a special smart pointer that can be used instead of a raw pointer. So user classes containing raw pointers (or Boost smart pointers, that internally own a raw pointer) can't be safely placed in a process shared mapped region. These pointers must be replaced with offset pointers, and these pointers must point only to objects placed in the same mapped region if you want to use these shared objects from different processes.

Of course, a pointer placed in a mapped region shared between processes should only point to an object of that mapped region. Otherwise, the pointer would point to an address that it's only valid one process and other processes may crash when accessing to that address.

Basile Starynkevitch wrote on April 21 2016, "The point is won't use pthread mutex and condition variable like you dream of. Be creative too..." , in response to my question about how to emulate a Windows event in Linux.
      So, I found the pdf, Implementing Condition Variables with Semaphores , http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64242/implementingcvs.pdf, written by Microsoft researcher , Andrew D. Birrell . Below . I show an excerpt from this article ,

```
class Lock {
 Semaphore sm;
public Lock() { // constructor
 sm = new Semaphore(); sm.count =1; sm.limit = 1;
 }
public void Acquire() { sm.P(); }
public void Release() { sm.V(); }
}
You can come quite close to implementing a condition variable in a similar way:
class CV {
 Semaphore s;
 Lock m;
public CV(Lock m) { // Constructor
 this.m = m;
 s = new Semaphore(); s.count = 0; s.limit = 1;
 }
public void Wait() { // Pre-condition: this thread holds “m”
 m.Release();
 s.P();
 m.Acquire();
 }
public void Signal() {
 s.V();
 }
}
```

Could I  harness Andrew D. Birrell's research to emulate a Windows event with a class like this:

```
class Event {
    Lock theLock;
    CV   theCV;
    bool triggered;

    Event* MakeEvent(string Name);
    Event* OpenEvent(string Name);
    void   CloseEvent(string Name, Event* anEvent);
    void   NukeEvent(string Name, Event* anEvent);
    void   SetEvent(Event* anEvent);
    void   ResetEvent(Event* anEvent);
    int    WaitForSingleObject(Event* anEvent, int millisecond);
}
```

?

Comment: Have you read https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ ?

Comment: There is a very nice article titled Sharing Mutex and Condition Variable Between Processes on April 10 2014  in this URLhttp://www.gonwan.com/page/3/. which forks  a child process.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, Thank you for the URL. I am reading it right now. How might I apply it to solving my problem?

Comment: I don't exactly know, because I don't have access to all your source code. But that URL is a possible answer to your "Have I confused threads with processes?" question.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, May I ask what source code I should add to the original question?

Comment: Perhaps the code in the question is enough, but I still find your entire question a bit unclear....

Comment: Can you be sure the pthread_mutex_t doesn't have a pointer to some allocated structure that it needs to change during lock and unlock? If not then this method won't work.

Comment: See [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html). Also, your libc (providing `pthread_mutex_lock`) is free software on Linux, so glance into the source code.

Comment: But if you care about inter-*process*-communication (between genuine processes, not threads) see also [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html). You need to care about *synchronization* issues.

Comment: @ratchet freak. Here is  our struct pthread_mutex_t, typedef struct {
    int reserved;
    int count;
    uint64_t owner;      from http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/uinc/bits/pthreadtypes.h. Could you pleas tell me whether the mmap cast will work with this struct? Thank you
    int kind;
    jthread_mutex_t jmu;
} pthread_mutex_t;  from

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, Thank you for your comments. I just scaned shm_overview(7) and it says "The POSIX shared memory API allows processes to communicate information by sharing a region of memory." If one wishes to share a region of memory , is forking necessary?

Comment: @ratchet freak, You are correct , our struct pthread_mutex_t contains a ypedef struct __pthread_internal_list
{
  struct __pthread_internal_list *__prev;
  struct __pthread_internal_list *__next;
} __pthread_list_t; which is a pointer to some allocates structure that needs to change during locking and unlocking. Thank you.

Comment: @gnat, I just removed some sentences. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, Could you point me to a URL with a futex code  example? Thank you.

Comment: *futexes* are practically used only for libc implementors (with the help of some assembler code, probably). So look into GNU libc or MUSL libc.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, Thank you for your reply. I have a question about Figure 11.10, Using a mutex to protect a data structure on page 372 in the book "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment Second Edition" by W. Richard Stevens and Stephen A. Rago. Figure 11.10 uses malloc(sizeof(struct foo)) to allocate the reference counted object. May one use this example to share a mutex between processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Pthread mutexes to synchronize between *processes*, at least on Linux. (I am not sure that Linux is implementing [pthread_mutexattr_setpshared](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html) correctly and efficiently, at least [not in GNU glibc 2.21](https://fossies.org/diffs/glibc/2.21_vs_2.22/nptl/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.c-diff.html)).

Use POSIX semaphores, see [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html). Or consider the Linux specific [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) probably with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) & [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) & [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html). Both (semaphores & `eventfd`-s) are alternative synchronization mechanisms (to mutex between *processes*).

You might also study the source code of your C# implementation (both Mono and Microsoft CLR are today free software). And you might also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to understand what your C# program is doing.

The point is that you won't use pthread mutex & condvar like you dream of. You need to be creative. If using `eventfd`, you might have some additional thread polling it, and then broadcast a condvar ... If using semaphores, be creative too...

Comment: Where could I find an example of using POSIX semaphores and eventfd to signal pthread condition variables? Thank you

Comment: You won't signal condvar with semaphores or eventfd-s. Both are different synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: If I cannot signal pthread condition variables with semaphores or eventfd-s, how can I signal pthread condition variables for  interprocess communication purposes? Thank you.

Comment: You need to give up using condition variables the way you dream.

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch, Thank you for your response today "about  giving up using condition variables the way I dream of." Could I ask you to briefly review my question I just inserted at the end of the original question about emulating Windows events in Linux?

Comment: I know nothing about Windows. I invite you to try thinking the Linux way. Mimicking some other OS is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Jules, May I ask you to briefly review my question I just inserted at the end of the original question about emulating Windows events in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_mutex_t` is not designed to work cross process like that. It was built with the assumption that all threads using it will have the same address space.

There are however other options to share a mutex between processes. As discussed in the comments there is `futex(7)` (which will work over shared memory) and `sem_overview(7)` (an explicit named semaphore shared across processes) both of these will work cross process.

Comment: I just read your excellent answer. I ran the Linux command , ps -ef , and it showed different process ids for the video server and the recorder.

Comment: How is a Linux explicit named semaphore shared across processes? I realize a named semaphore is different than a pthreads mutex. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank when you do "sem_open" the OS will look for other semaphores with the same name and return a handle to an existing semaphore if there is already one (creating one otherwise if the flag was set). Waiting and signaling semaphores are system calls and the kernel will deal with the exclusive access.

Comment: I have a question about Figure 11.10, Using a mutex to protect a data structure on page 372 of "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment Second Edition" by W. Richard Stevens and Stephen A. Rago. Figure 11.10 uses malloc(sizeof(struct foo)) to allocate the reference counted object. May one use this example to share a mutex between processes?

Comment: A `pthread_mutex_t` is for locking inside *threads* of the *same* process. Use [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) for inter-*process* synchronization. So don't share any `pthread_mutex_t`  between different processes.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, I appreciate your sense of honor in answering my questions over the past 4 days. I just added an excerpt from Herb Sutter's Boost documentation about the limitations of sharing memory between processes to the tail end of the original question. It says that "raw pointers are a problem since they are only valid for the process that placed them there".  ratchet_freak said that since pthread_mutex_t contained a raw pointer member  it would have problems with interprocess synchronization.  Could I email you about how to use Boost.Interprocess special smart pointer?

Comment: You can email me (my email is really easy to find), but I know nothing about Boost...

Comment: @Frank - Sutter's comments are really quite specific to working on shared memory in a C++ environment.  Under C#, you would find it extremely difficult to place a pointer into shared memory simply because you don't tend (unless working with unsafe extensions) to ever have access to raw pointers in that language.  I'd suggest forgetting about pthreads, which really has nothing to do with your problem, and using one of the other mutex implementations already mentioned, or the alternative I'm about to suggest in an answer...

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd forget about using either pthreads (which only works on threads and not processes, and you're clearly using multiple processes) or shared memory of the kind you're talking about, as transferring the handles between processes is going to be a bit of a pain point when working in C#.

A simpler technique, which is becoming increasing frequent in Linux software, is to create a file in a transient storage area (e.g. /run/shm in Linux distributions using the Filesystem Heirarchy Standard 3.0 or higher, or /var/shm in older systems - I don't use Ubuntu but I can see that the version you're using is recent, and as it's based on Debian whose current version is based on FHS 3.0 I suspect you should be using /run), and then open that in both processes, and use `mmap` (or [Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.mmap](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall.mmap) in your case) to map the file into both processes' memory space.  Once you've done this, you can share data simply by reading & writing into the mapped area.

For mutual exclusion, a similar process can be performed by creating an empty file (typically in /run/lock or /var/lock) and then using `lockf` (also both in [Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall.lockf)).  Alternatively, you can use a [`System.Threading.Semaphore` constructed with a system-wide name](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=C%3aSystem.Threading.Semaphore.Semaphore%28System.Int32%2cSystem.Int32%2cSystem.String%29).

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. As shown below,                                      public static int lockf (int fd, LockfCommand cmd, long len) takes an integer  file descriptor rather than a file pointer. How do I handle that? Could I convert a linux file pointer to an linux file descriptor?

Comment: Do we have to mmap the empty file for mutual exclusion? Thank you.

Comment: The simplest way is to use the `open` method in the same class to open a file and return its file descriptor.  And you don't need to map the lock file, on the data file.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating a file in transient storage area of and then opening that in both processes, and use mmap  to map the file into both processes' memory space. as well as sharing the data by reading & writing into the mapped area? We understand the purpose of your mutual exclusion. Thank you.

Comment: The transient file exists to create a globally-accessible name that any process can refer to.  It also defines the size of the memory block that can be shared between the processes.  By using mmap on the same file, any processes can gain access to the same shared data.  Using the /run filesystem prevents the overhead of the data ever being flushed to disk, as it is (typically) a memory-only filesystem ("tmpfs").

Comment: When should we use the transient file as opposed to to the empty file? Thank you.

Comment: Use the file in /run/shm to map the memory, use the empty one in /run/lock to provide lock operations in order to sequence modifications to it.  Or just use System.Threading.Semaphore, which is likely to be easier.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. What causes the following pthread_mutex_init segmentation fault?                                                                                                        pMutex = (pthread_mutex_t *)mmap(0, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, hSHM, 0);
if (pMutex != nullptr) 
{
   // Initialize with process shared attribute
   pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
   pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
   pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
   pthread_mutex_init(pMutex, &attr); /* SEGMENTATION FAULT */
}

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. Basile Starynkevitch just answered my above question. I have another question. Suppose I have a Linux event consisting of 1) a struct pthread_mutex_t   2) a struct pthread_cond_t. What is the correct way to achieve Linux event synchronization and signaling with the most recent GNU glib API's and libraries?